# Testing model fit and running model validation plots for averaged models

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, validation

I have carried out a model selection process and averaged the models within the top 2 AICcs (using MuMIn in R).  I would like to test the model fit using both the chisq and validation/residual plots.  I'm unsure how to write the code for this, or indeed if it is even possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Trying to understand at which step you are having a difficulty... Are you able to do that for other models rather than what `MuMIn` returns (so that it is `MuMin` that is the trouble)? Or are you unable to do that for any model (so that `MuMIn` itself is not the trouble)? What do you mean by *test the model fit using ... chisq*?

Comment: I can do both diagnostics for singular models using MuMIn and other packages.  The issue is how do you run diagnostics on averaged models.

Comment: How is an averaged model different from a simple model so that these tests cannot be readily conducted on it? Is it due to `MuMIn` model output belonging to some "weird" class in `R`, or is there also a conceptual difference? If it is just a "wrong class" problem, have you tried changing the class of the model to one that would fit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that an "averaged" model through MuMIn is actually stored as a list of the input models with a few new attributes. It is not actually the "output" model. Every time you print or summarize the model.avg output, it re-generates the averaged outputs from the list for display. You will need to manually generate the components of the diagnostic plots using predict and then do the math.